# Capistrano error: Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, capistrano, sprockets

I am using the `gem "bootstrap-sass"` gem.

In `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

in `application.css.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

On localhost works everything perfectly, but when I try to deploy the code using `Capistrano`, I get this error message:

```
  ...
  * executing "cd -- /home/deployer/apps/app-name/releases/20140805182229 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
 ** [out :: IP] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: IP]
 ** [out :: IP] Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets'
 ** [out :: IP]
 ** [out :: IP] (in /home/deployer/apps/app-name/releases/20140805182229/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:17)
...
```

The line `#17` points here:

> //= require bootstrap-sprockets

Why is that & what am I missing here?

Comment: I am getting the same error.  Any progress?

Comment: I think I have the same problem.  However I'm not using capistrano but my error appears when the app fails to deploy to heroku.  Working from there, it appears to be that the assets won't compile.
`$rake assets:precompile`
`rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`
    `rake aborted!`
    `Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets'`

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/692  Looks like a bug

Comment: My problem appears to be using Rails 3.2.x Reading https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master and the link to
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html gives more detail.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but seemed to solve the problem by restarting the server after you bundle install. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I was able to fix this issue by moving gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1' to the top of the Gemfile, underneath the gem 'rails' line. I don't know why it breaks if it's after refinerycms in the Gemfile.